# How to send notification to users that a newer version is available for my app in google play?

Tags: android, notifications

How to send info to already installed users about the update ?

Comment: whoever down voted this question, please comment why it's down voted

Answer (score 1):

You can use push notification here from below link you can get detail information about it

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I did it:

1. Put a text file one some server, containing the latest version's "VersionCode"
2. In your app, check the current version code with the one on the text file. If there's a newer version code - show a notification to the user.
3. You can check everytime the user starts the app, or write a service that runs every 1-2 weeks (depends how often you publish new versions)

Using this method, you don't need to have a DB with all your users' versions and GCM reg ids.

Hope this helped!